# forkJoin with Observable<void>

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Observable. If it succeed I want to give user feedback and then refresh data on the page. So what I did is to call the `do` operator for the user feedback, and then call a `forkJoin` to refresh the data. The issue is that it's not possible to call the `forkJoin` after a `do` with the following error: `Error:(37, 12) TS2339: Property 'forkJoin' does not exist on type 'Observable<void>'.`

The code:

```
this.pickService.activate(event)
  .do(() => this.snackBar.open(`Pick activated`, null, {duration: 5000}))
  .forkJoin([
    this.pickService.get('DRAFT', 'dt,asc'),
    this.pickService.get('PENDING', 'dt,desc')
  ])
  .subscribe(results => {
    this.draftPicks = results[0];
    this.pendingPicks = results[1];
  });
```

The Observable

```
  activate(id: string): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.patch<void>(`/api/v1/picks/${id}`, {status: 'PENDING'});
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forkJoin is just a observable-creating method. So I think what you are wanting to do is something like that:

```
let requests = [ this.pickService.get('DRAFT', 'dt,asc'),
                 this.pickService.get('PENDING', 'dt,desc') ];

this.pickService.activate(event)
                .do(() => this.snackBar.open(`Pick activated`, null, {duration: 5000}))
                .switchMap(a => Observable.forkJoin(requests))
                .subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

`forkJoin` is static creation method, not operator can chain. So you can do `Observable.forkJoin` only.